Improve readability of highlighted text in GitHub Dark High Contrast theme
vscode screenshot
vscode screenshot
vscode screenshot
When using the GitHub Dark High Contrast theme in VS Code, the system UI highlight uses white color to overlay text, which is also white. This makes the highlighted text unreadable, especially in areas like extension pages and other non-editor UI elements.
How to fix this?
I've set the workbench.colorCustomizations in settings.json, but it's not working.

You are looking in the right place.  Here is an example for making the text black on yellow:
{
      //...
      "workbench.colorTheme": "GitHub Dark High Contrast",
      "workbench.preferredDarkColorTheme": "GitHub Dark High Contrast",
      "workbench.preferredHighContrastColorTheme": "GitHub Dark High Contrast",
      "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
            "textPreformat.foreground": "#000000",
            "textPreformat.background": "#fffc44",
      }
    }

If you are using the textPreformat property and its not working, check to see if you are editing the "user" or "workspace" settings, and make sure they aren't being overridden.
